# Dynamic video Quiz in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube

I have 10 YouTube links and I want to be able to move to the next video by pressing the next button.

My code:

```
var videoLinks = ["https://www.youtube.com/embed/QIMo0jFbfQs",  "http://www.youtube.com/v/L8NGOUrw8UU"];
var v = 0;

$("#next").on('click', function(){
    next() + 1;

    function next(){
        if(v == videoLinks.length){ 
            //v = 0;
        }

        $(".content").html(" <iframe src= ' " + videoLinks[v]  + "'> "+ "</iframe>");    
    }
});
```

Note: I only included 2 links for testing.

Comment: Nowhere in your code do you increment `v`.

Answer (score 1):

You basically need a way to keep track of the vid count. Local Storage would be good for this.  The button would increment the video counter and reset the value if you reached the end. The counter would be a reference to the video source value.

Use a simple replace to change the video source, embed the video, and then increment the counter.

It can be seen here: https://jsbin.com/dehoxo/edit?html,js,console,output

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#nextBtn').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert();
    var vidIndex = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("vidIndex"));


    var vids = ['https://www.youtube.com/embed/VT4gri_n0iM', 
        'https://www.youtube.com/embed/DWooSca2rCw', 
       'https://www.youtube.com/embed/MukFRbS_5Gw'];

    var vidToken = '<iframe width="420" height="315" src="{{SRC}}" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';


    if (vidIndex) {
        if (vidIndex >= vids.length) {
            vidIndex = 0;
        }

    }
    else {
        if (!vidIndex && vidIndex !==0) {
            vidIndex = 0;
        }
    }

    var currentVid = vidToken.replace('{{SRC}}', vids[vidIndex]);
    $('#vidBox').html(currentVid);
    $('#vidIndex').val(vidIndex);
    vidIndex++;
    localStorage.setItem('vidIndex', vidIndex);
});
```

});

The HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="vidBox">
        NO VID
    </div>
    <button id="nextBtn">Next Vid</button>
    <input id="vidIndex"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var videoLinks = [link1, link2, link3, ...];
var v = 0;

var iframe = $('iframe');
iframe.attr('src', videoLinks[0]);

$("#next").on('click', function(){
    v++;
    if(v >= videoLinks.length){
        v = 0;
    }

    iframe.attr('src', videoLinks[v]);
});
```

Comment: Please provide an explanation of how this code solves the question. This will help the OP understand the solution and also helps future searchers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it's a little more concise and easier to read:

```
var videoLinks = ["https://www.youtube.com/embed/QIMo0jFbfQs", "https://www.youtube.com/embed/L8NGOUrw8UU"];
var v = 0;

$("#next").on('click', function() {
  $(".content").html(" <iframe src= ' " + videoLinks[v] + "'> " + "</iframe>");
  v == videoLinks.length - 1 ? v = 0 : v++;
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j0pv6yeq/3/)